# how to get post_id of a Facebook post (programmatically)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to get post_id of a Facebook post programmatically, for example, I see a post on my wall, what is the best way to get its post_id programmatically.

thanks Gurus.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously extremely difficult to due since the nature of facebook's feed and the framework it uses (reactjs). They do not want you to get post_ids and they do not want you to mimic their service. The most you'll get is id's like r.2.15, etc, which will mean nothing to you.

Answer (score 0):

See, whenever you post a comment (using Graph API), you get the `post_id` in return.

But if you want the post id of a feed that was not published using Graph API, you can do-

- get all the feeds with `\GET /user-id/feed` You'll get message, description, id and other details
- check for for your post and get the `id`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the post ids using graph api. If you have a valid access token you can try this below code to get the post ids. Here we are using page /feed to get the posts. you can use page /posts to get only page posts.

```
$fb_page = ''; //your page name
$access_token = ''; //your access token
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/".$fb_page.'/feed?access_token='.$access_token;
$curl = curl_init($url);    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($curl);  
curl_close($curl);  
$details = json_decode($result,true);
$posts = $details['data'];
foreach ($posts as $post)
{
    echo "<p>".$post['id']."</p>";
}
```